# GNUPLOT line 0: invalid command

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to run this gnuplot script:

```
set terminal pngcairo transparent crop size 1440,900
set title 'velocities eps=0.5'
unset key

do for [i=1:10] {
  if(i==1){
     plot i.'v0.5.dat' ps 0.2
  } else {
    replot i.'v0.5.dat' ps 0.2
  }
}

set output 'v0.5.png'
replot
```

With the command "gnuplot -e plotvel.gp". Then I get this response from terminal:

```
plotvel.gp
^
line 0: invalid command
```

Where am I failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-e` command line option is to execute a *command*, not pass a filename to a file containing commands. For example you could execute the `load` command to load the file:

```
$ gnuplot -e 'load plotlevel.gp'
```

However, to just load the file (as if using the `load` command) just passit without any special options:

```
$ gnuplot plotlevel.gp
```

This is all in [the documentation](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_5.0/gnuplot.pdf).